# get_flashed_messages() raises an error sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

when I try to flash message **sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError** appears and when I remove the bellow HTML code there is no any error, but the flashed message is displayed. Can anyone please help me with that??? :(

```
<div>
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
    <ul>
        {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                <li>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
    {% endwith %}
</div>
```

the error:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError
DetachedInstanceError: Instance <User at 0x7f2f54fc8750> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to play around and I found my mistake. In fact there is no problem with HTML code. The problem was with my view code. Specifically, when I deleted a user I tried to flash deleted username and the flashed message I guess stacked, thus it gave me that error.

I am not sure about my point, but it worked for me. 
If you know the better solution please post your answer :)